# Issue with Cell Frames in version 11

Tags: bugs, frame

Since upgrading to version 11, all of my notebooks now have cell frames are either missing the top or bottom part.   Is anyone else experiencing this?  Is there a way to fix this?  Is this considered a bug?

Below is gif illustrating the issue with a fresh install of Mathematica 11.0.1 on MacOS 10.12.12.

[image]

Comment: Beautifully illustrated. I have noticed the same problem under Mac OS X 10.9.5 with v11. Sometimes the top of the frame goes missing ... sometimes the bottom. The same frames have operated correctly in all previous versions. I have been meaning to send in a bug report ... so pleased to see someone else has the same issue.

Comment: I've had it too, and corresponded with Wolfram about it. In my case, whether a particular top border appears or not depends on what comes before it and, in particular, whether it's expanded or collapsed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue, as I've experienced it, derives from cases where the `CellFrame` is fractional. In my experience generally .75 works for the bottom while .5 works for the top. This holds in the case illustrated. There also appears to be no visual difference in my experience between .5, .75, and 1 in the line thickness.

As something interesting, try running this:

```
Table[CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], CellFrame] = f; 
 Pause[.1], {f, Range[.5, 3, .25]}]
```

And similarly see the difference between:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], CellFrame] = {{.5, .2}, {.75, .5}}
```

and

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], CellFrame] = {{.5, .2}, {.5, .75}}
```

(on my machine everything appears in the first case while in the second only the top disappears).

Note that .25 works for all the borders.

Also try:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], CellFrame] = .5;
Monitor[
  Table[CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], 
     CellFrameMargins] = {{Inherited, Inherited}, {i, Inherited}};
   Pause[.1],
   {i, Range[0, 10, .1]}],
  i
  ];
```

Non-integral values display while integral values do not for me.

Odd issue, but I get around it by just generally sticking to using .25 or 1 instead of .5 or .75.

Comment: On my Windows 7 PC, CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], CellFrame] = 0.5 is missing the bottom and for 0.75 is missing the top,

Comment: Good to know this applies on Windows too. Well, perhaps not good, but interesting.

Comment: This behavior appears to be execution-order-dependent.  Compare [nb1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5cjU.png) and [nb2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaVly.png).  (Note that the right edge of the frames is lighter than in the actual notebooks.)

Comment: Definitely is. It's a weird quirk that I'm surprised made it through the testing phase.

Comment: I recommend that the question be tagged with "bug" and that the problem be reported to Wolfram, Inc.

Comment: I have reported the bug to wolfram.  I have prerelease download 11.1.  It is not fixed.  Hopefully in the next version.